# How to tell if a ViewModel is already shown?

Tags: mvvmcross

I have a command that shows a view model:

```
private void DoShowImportCommand()
{
    this.ShowViewModel<GeometryImportViewModel>();
}
```

but I only want to execute it if that view model isn't already shown.  Is there a way to
detect if that view model is already on screen and if so don't execute the command?

Answer (score 1):

MvvmCross doesn't track this by default - what is currently shown depends on the UI and can be interpreted in different ways in different situations (popups, tabs, pivots, dialogs, back stacks, etc)

If you want to track this in your own application, you could do it using UI project components (e.g. custom presenters) or you could do it using a shared code component - e.g. you could add "alive" tracking to the Views/ViewModels (see the N=42 video on http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com) and could then use some service to track which viewmodels are shown.